# Selected item in a Flex Tree is not highlighted after dragging and dropping it

Tags: apache-flex

I have a Flex (3.5) Tree with drag & drop support, but the problem is that after I drag an item (node) and drop it, it's supposed to be the selected item in the tree, but for some reason it's not highlighted. Does anyone know how I can fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Show some code; I'm pretty sure that after dropping an item onto a Tree nothing in the tree is selected.

Comment: There's not really any code to show, because the drag & drop can be automatically enabled on the tree by setting the properties dragEnabled and dropEnabled to true. Anyway, if as you say, no item is selected after dropping, how can I programmatically select and highlight it? Setting the tree's selectedItem property in the dragDrop event didn't work...

Comment: If you're having a problem, but don't have code to share with us to demonstrate the problem it's tough to help you.  But, I made an attempt at a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to set the tree's [selectedItem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#selectedItem) property in the [dragComplete](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event%3adragComplete) event.

Comment: Didn't work... I tried to attach some code, but I'm new to this site and interface and don't know how to format it properly. When I try to press Enter to start a new line, it posts my comment...

Comment: You can't add line breaks in comments.  To add code, edit your original post, don't try to add it as a comment.  There is also a "curly bracket" button which allows you to format the code nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too; and based on the fact that the tree had not re-settled visually when the onDragComplete breakpoint tripped, I placed the following in my onDragComplete handler method:

```
            callLater(function():void{
                treeGrid.selectedItem = draggedItem;
            });
```

That worked-selected item was highlighted.